# gulp-uglify minifying script that it is not supposed to

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify, gulp-rename

When I run `gulp scripts`, both all.js and all.min.js end up minified. Anybody know why this happens?

```
gulp.task("scripts", function() {

    var concatted = gulp.src(['js/first.js', 'js/second.js'])
                        .pipe(concat('all.js'));

    // output concatenated scripts to js/all.js
    concatted.pipe(gulp.dest('js'));

    // minify concatenated scripts and output to js/all.min.js
    concatted.pipe(uglify())
             .pipe(rename('all.min.js')
             .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here

```
// output concatenated scripts to js/all.js
concatted.pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
```

You aren't returning the modified stream into `concatted`.

You could change this to

```
// output concatenated scripts to js/all.js
concatted = concatted.pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
```

but this also works as expected

```
gulp.task("scripts", function() {
    return gulp.src(['js/first.js', 'js/second.js'])
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename('all.min.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot, I'm new to gulp and the tutorial I did on it didn't return anything in the tasks.

Comment: Returning the stream is one way to make your tasks asynchronous. You should make your tasks asynchronous if you ever want to use them as dependencies in other tasks. See https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you're concatenating the two scripts

```
var concatted = gulp.src(['js/first.js', 'js/second.js'])
                    .pipe(concat('all.js'));
                    // Both scripts are now in 'all.js'
```

Before minifying them

```
concatted.pipe(uglify())
         .pipe(rename('all.min.js')
         .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
```

One possible solution could be:

```
gulp.src('js/first.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I edited/reworded my question for clarity. I want to have the concatenated scripts output to two files: all.js and all.min.js. For some reason all.js ends up minified too.